# What is the Mother of All Bombs or MOAB killstreak reward?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I've seen a couple of online rumors about a killstreak or strike package reward when you get 25 consecutive kills that is similar to the tactical nuke from previous Modern Warfare games.

Allegedly it kills every player on the map.

Is this a confirmed part of the game or just rumor?

if it does exist - is it part of a specific strike package : i.e assault, support or specialist?

Any information on this would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know for sure so leaving this as a comment, but I'm pretty sure I read that the devs caught a lot of flak for the tactical nuke so they decided not to include anything so over the top, even for a ridiculous 25 kill streak. Source: Memory (unreliable)

Comment: Darn, I saw MOAB, and thought this was a question about Mother of all Battles.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is a "secret" killstreak (25, excluding strike package kills, or 24 with Hardline) that's not bound to a specific strike package.

It is similar to the Tactical Nuke in Modern Warfare 2 — using it triggers a countdown, and a bomb drops. However, unlike the Nuke, it "only" kills the entire enemy team (as opposed to all players) and disables their equipment and killstreaks for a bit.

It does **not** end the match, though it awards double XP for the remainder of the match for the team that used it.

Comment: Do you have a source you can link?

Comment: @Yatrix Well, I have [this Activision help document](http://activision.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/activision.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=77706).

Comment: I also believe it can only be achieved by weapons kills, not other streaks.

Comment: I didn't see it the Strike Package menu. If it is secret, I don't think I'll ever be able to see it. But, does that mean, as soon as I reach 25, I'll get it; I mean, no "selecting" the nuke as we did in MW2? So, effectively, I have 4 killstreak rewards?

Answer (score 0):

A MOAB is what you get after 25 kills.  It kills the enemy team once and sets off an EMP, which lasts for the rest of the round (or match if it's TDM, Sabotage, etc.)  Also, it gives Double XP for the team who earned the MOAB.