# How do you select the Fourth kill streak?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

On one of the loading screens for MW3 I noticed an "intel" text that said something similar to this: "You can choose 3 kill streaks for support, assault, or specialist. You also can choose one other kill streak that occurs regardless of your strike package"

I've heard about the [M.O.A.B](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34500/what-is-the-mother-of-all-bombs-or-moab-killstreak-reward) but this implies that you can choose your own killstreak. What exactly does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

You can not select the fourth "M.O.A.B." kill streak for any strike package configuration.  The only way to obtain it is to get a 25 kill streak with your primary weapon, secondary weapon, equipment and/or knife.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that you have one extra slot to hold killstreaks obtained through other means. For example, if you took a killstreak from a care package it would be stored in that fourth slot. It's there so you can have your three killstreaks and still be able to take care packages.